# How to select ng-show attributes with specific structure within HTML files with queryselectall?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jspdf, dom-manipulation, queryselectall

[this is the html structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrAOL.png)

I have attached the picture of the html structure, I would like to pick up with the queryselectall all elements that have ng-show="'EN' == defaultLanguage" that are printable, i.e. have non-hidden content.

```
var actualLanguage = sessionStorage.getItem("defaultLanguage").toUpperCase().replace(/"/g, '');
                  
var elementsToPrint = document.querySelectorAll('[data-printpdf="true"], [data-isvisible="true"] div:not(.ng-hide) > [data-printgeneratedpdf="true"],[ng-show="true"]');
```

this is the queryselectall that I must also use to get the contents of ng-show in Italian.